Why does my CLIP model (aims for text-based person retrieval) show an improvement only in the few epochs before performance begins to decline?
I'm training a model aims to achieve the goal of person retrieval based on text description, which is a sub-subject of ReID(Re-identification problem). I used a pre-trained CLIP model as my backbone, and also create a new loss. Then I start to train on some baseline dataset: CUHK-PEDES, ICFG-PEDES, IIITD-20K, RSTPReid.
But I found that on CUHK-PEDES, ICFG-PEDES, IIITD-20K these three datasets, the model perform well, and the following pic is the relevant performance changing with epochs:
performance on three datasets
However, when I tried to train my model on RSTPReid dataset, the relevant performance can be visualized as this:
performance on RSTPReid
I didn't change my params or other items, this model illustrated a common result on all the datasets except RSTPReid.
I want to know why it has this result? How can I fix it? Is the model overfitting on RSTPReid?
